# New Angular 1 Component Router - Highlighting the link associated with the active route

Tags: angularjs, angular-component-router

I have a navbar with two links:

```
<nav>
  <a ng-link="['Route1']">Route 1</a>
  <a ng-link="['Route2']">Route 2</a>
</nav>
```

I would like to highlight the link associated with the active route. Essentially, I would like to add a class called `router-link-active` to one of the two links above. What's the easiest way to do this for the new Angular 1 Component Router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The ComponentRouter for Angular 1 is now deprecated. For using angular 1.5 components, it's recommended to use the well-known ui-router.

---

Angular 1 Component Router automatically adds the `ng-link-active` class to active `ng-link`s.

If your version isn't adding this automatically, you are probably using an outdated version of the Component Router. I've been using [this version](https://github.com/excellalabs/ngComponentRouter) which is a more recent compilation rather than the one stated on the docs (which is 0.2.0).

Let's hope they get it production-ready soon.

Comment: Thank for the reference, Daniel. I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't want to go with a "non-official" release, so i created my own directive that adds ng-link-active (see below).

Notes:

1. You need to make sure that "path" and "name" properties in your routes are the same (other than "/", ":" and capitalization which are ignored) - I don't love this limitation but it's OK for me until a fixed version is released.
2. This is in ES6 but should be clear enough even if you write your code in ES5.

   ```
   export const isActive =
   /*@ngInject*/
   function ($location) {
       return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: linkFunc,
       };

       /**
        * Adds active class to ng-link matching current route
        *
        * @param {Object} scope
        * @param {Object} element
        * @param {Object} attrs
        *  @param {String} attrs.ngLink
        *  @param {Function} attrs.$addClass
        *  @param {Function} attrs.$removeClass
        */
       function linkFunc (scope, element, attrs) {

           const activeClass = 'ng-link-active';

           scope.$watch(getUrl, setClass);

           function getUrl () {
               return $location.url();
           }

           function setClass () {
               // eg "/books/..." -> 'books'
               const pathName = $location.url().split('/')[1].toLowerCase();
               // eg "['Books']" -> 'books'
               const routeName = attrs.ngLink ? (attrs.ngLink.split('\'')[1].toLowerCase()) : '';

               if (pathName === routeName) {
                   attrs.$addClass(activeClass);
                   return;
               }
               attrs.$removeClass(activeClass);
           } // setClass

       } // linkFunc

   };
   ```